# Will an object me overridden if it has the same name as another object?

Tags: java, class

I basically need to allow users create multiple objects and store them in an array.

How can I do this in a way so that the previous object won't be overwritten when a new one is made.

For example, when a new one is made, it would appear in the form:

```
UndergradTA student = new UndergradTA();
```

It will then be stored in an array with its information.

but if a new  one is made, it would still be named "student". Wouldn't it then overwrite the previous object?

Comment: Your question is confusing. Objects don't "override" each other, and objects don't have names either. Variables have names, but they're not nearly as important as you might imagine them to be. Are you looking to use an ArrayList and not an array? Is that your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you code:

```
Object myVar = new Object();
```

You are stating that myVar will be a reference to a new instance of an object.  If you then execute a second assignment:

```
myVar = new Object();
```

Then the original reference will be lost.

However, if you have an array:

```
Object myArray[] = new Object[5];
myArray[0] = new Object();
myArray[1] = new Object();
...
```

Then the references will not be lost.  They will be accessible via indexing into the array.

Answer (score 0):

If you place these objects in the array then you wont lose your reference to them. student = new UndergradTA() is simply assigning student to refer to the new object. Once the array already refers to this object then you are fine to reassign student.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you have a reference to your object it won't be garbage collected. The following example gives you the idea.

```
public class Main {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
 List<Foo> myList = new ArrayList<Foo>();
 Random random = new Random();
 for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
     Foo foo = new Foo(random.nextInt());
     myList.add(foo);
 } 
 for (Foo foo : myList ) {
     System.out.println(foo);
 }
}
}

class Foo {
  private int val;
  Foo(int val ){
      this.val = val;
  }

  public String toString() {
      return "foo.val = " + val;
  }
}
```